# How to make flood fill rollover buttons?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple web page for homework. It has rollover buttons for each week, they change colour on mouseover. Very old!

Now this is no kind of advertising, I have nothing to do with them, except, now and again I play lotto [here](https://www.ventura24.es/). (Just to show the buttons.)

They had problems with the authorities in Spain and were offline a while. Now they are back with cool rollover buttons which flood fill.

My webpage is very simple, but I have rollover buttons lined up just like in the link.

Could anyone give me a pointer, link, tip as to how this is done?

Comment: Go to the lotto page, open the browser console and have a look at the button's css. You'll find some hints when you investigate the a-element and it's ::after-element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `:after` element and transition the `height` of it on `:hover`.

`z-index` will make sure your colour stays behind the content within the box.

I have created an example for you here:

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

li a {
  z-index: 20; /*this will keep your content above the colour*/
  position: relative;
}

li:after {
  z-index: 10; /*this will keep your colour behind the content*/
  background-color: #bf1f1f;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: height .3s; /*creates smooth animation*/
}

li:hover:after {
  height: 100%; /*toggling the height to 100% on hover of the box*/
}
```

```html
<li><a href="/">Example List Item</a></li>
```

Here's an example with multiple items:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

li a {
  z-index: 20;
  /*this will keep your content above the colour*/
  position: relative;
}

li:after {
  z-index: 10;
  /*this will keep your colour behind the content*/
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: height .3s;
  /*creates smooth animation*/
}

li:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
  /*toggling the height to 100% on hover of the box*/
}

li:nth-child(1):after {
  background-color: #c50202;
}

li:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: #4444de;
}

li:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: #279027;
}

li:nth-child(4):after {
  background-color: #e07832;
}

li:nth-child(5):after {
  background-color: #c50202;
}

li:nth-child(6):after {
  background-color: #4444de;
}

li:nth-child(7):after {
  background-color: #279027;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Example List Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Example List Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Example List Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Example List Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Example List Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Example List Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Example List Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! Just 1 small thing: my buttons now do not line up across the page, but on top of each other.  My old mystyle.css has: li {style="display:inline;" 
vertical-align: middle; float: left; margin:0px } How to tweak your code to make them line up horizontally?

Comment: I set: li {   display: inline-table; That fixed it! Thanks again!